# Conditionally filling in missing values while reshaping a long to wide dataset in R

Tags: r, reshape, missing-data, reshape2

I am constructing complete timelines of indicators for a set of years and countries on the basis of multiple datasets with varying quality.

Using `reshape2` I have "melted" those datasets into a single dataframe.

Example dataset:

```
d <- structure(list(cntry = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 
1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L), .Label = c("BE", 
"DE", "GE"), class = "factor"), year = c(1960L, 1970L, 1980L, 
1960L, 1970L, 1960L, 1970L, 1960L, 1970L, 1960L, 1970L, 1960L, 
1970L, 1960L, 1970L, 1960L, 1970L, 1970L, 1980L), indicator = c(5.5, 
1.2, 1.5, NA, 1.4, NA, NA, 5.5, 1.2, 2.3, 1.4, NA, 1.4, NA, NA, 
2.3, 1.4, 1.4, NA), sex = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), .Label = "male", class = "factor"), 
    source = structure(c(2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 
    3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), .Label = c("Council", 
    "Eurostat", "OECD"), class = "factor")), .Names = c("cntry", 
"year", "indicator", "sex", "source"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-19L))


d
#    cntry year indicator  sex   source
# 1     BE 1960       5.5 male Eurostat
# 2     BE 1970       1.2 male Eurostat
# 3     BE 1980       1.5 male Eurostat
# 4     DE 1960        NA male Eurostat
# 5     DE 1970       1.4 male Eurostat
# 6     GE 1960        NA male Eurostat
# 7     GE 1970        NA male Eurostat
# 8     BE 1960       5.5 male     OECD
# 9     BE 1970       1.2 male     OECD
# 10    DE 1960       2.3 male     OECD
# 11    DE 1970       1.4 male     OECD
# 12    GE 1960        NA male     OECD
# 13    GE 1970       1.4 male     OECD
# 14    BE 1960        NA male  Council
# 15    BE 1970        NA male  Council
# 16    DE 1960       2.3 male  Council
# 17    DE 1970       1.4 male  Council
# 18    GE 1970       1.4 male  Council
# 19    GE 1980        NA male  Council
```

I was hoping I could uses `cast()` with `fun.aggregate` to convert this long dataset into the wide format, while selecting the most high quality dataset (Eurostat > OECD > Council) for a given country-year combination to fill in the missings. Unfortunately I do not really understand how to work with such a custom aggregate function.

In other words, I want to reshape the dataset from a long to a wide format while merging multiple values depending on the value of a factor ("source"). Ideally it would work something as:

```
full_data <- expand.grid(c('BE', 'GE', 'DE'), c('1960', '1970', '1980'))
full_data <- fill_missings(full_data, d, pref_order=c('Eurostat', 'OECD', 'Council'))
full_data
# BE 1960 5.5 male Eurostat
# BE 1970 1.2 male Eurostat
# BE 1980 1.5 male Eurostat
# DE 1960 2.3 male OECD
# DE 1970 1.4 male Eurostat
# DE 1980 NA  NA   NA
# GE 1960 NA  male Council 
# GE 1970 1.4 male OECD
# GE 1980 NA  male Council
```

and optionally (or directly) into the wide format:

```
# cntry  sex 1960 1970 1980
#    BE male  5.5  1.2  1.5
#    DE male  2.3  1.4  NA
#    GE male   NA  1.4  NA
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming that the data is in the order you require, that is, column `source` is ordered first by `Eurostat`, then by `OECD` and then by `council`, I'd go about using `data.table` in this manner:

```
require(data.table) # >= v1.9.0
setDT(d) # converts data.frame to data.table by reference
dcast.data.table(d, cntry + sex ~ year, value.var="indicator", 
 subset=.(!duplicated(d, by=c("cntry", "year", "indicator")) & !is.na(indicator)))

#    cntry  sex 1960 1970 1980
# 1:    BE male  5.5  1.2  1.5
# 2:    DE male  2.3  1.4   NA
# 3:    GE male   NA  1.4   NA
```

Comment: nice concise solution

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure if this meets all of your expectations, but it sounds like you're looking for something like the following:

```
toMerge <- expand.grid(cntry = c("BE", "DE", "GE"), 
                       year = c(1960, 1970, 1980), 
                       source = c("Eurostat", "OECD", "Council"), 
                       sex = "male")
d2 <- merge(d, toMerge, all = TRUE)

d2$source <- factor(d2$source, c("Council", "OECD", "Eurostat"), ordered=TRUE)
d2 <- d2[order(d2$source, decreasing=TRUE), ]
Rank <- with(d2, ave(indicator, d2[c("cntry", "year", "sex")], 
                 FUN = function(x) rank(x, ties.method="first", na.last=TRUE)))
D <- d2[Rank == 1, ]
D
#    cntry year  sex   source indicator
# 2     BE 1960 male Eurostat       5.5
# 5     BE 1970 male Eurostat       1.2
# 8     BE 1980 male Eurostat       1.5
# 14    DE 1970 male Eurostat       1.4
# 17    DE 1980 male Eurostat        NA
# 20    GE 1960 male Eurostat        NA
# 26    GE 1980 male Eurostat        NA
# 12    DE 1960 male     OECD       2.3
# 24    GE 1970 male     OECD       1.4

library(reshape2)
dcast(D, cntry ~ year, value.var="indicator")
#   cntry 1960 1970 1980
# 1    BE  5.5  1.2  1.5
# 2    DE  2.3  1.4   NA
# 3    GE   NA  1.4   NA
```

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps the following could work as well:

```
library(reshape2)
x <- melt(d,id.vars=c("cntry","year","source","sex"))
y <- dcast(x,cntry+year+sex ~ source)
y$selected.value <- ifelse(is.na(y$Eurostat),yes=ifelse(is.na(y$OECD),yes=y$Council,no=y$OECD),no=y$Eurostat)
dcast(y,cntry + sex ~ year)
```

The source selection is made using a layered `ifelse` statement. The indication of the source selected is lost with this approach, if that is an issue, a similar `ifelse` statement can be added, creating the source origin variable:

```
y$selected.source <- ifelse(is.na(y$Eurostat),yes=ifelse(is.na(y$OECD),yes="Council",no="OECD"),no="Eurostat")
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is another option:

```
library(reshape2)
d$source <- factor(d$source, levels=c('Eurostat', 'OECD', 'Council'))
d2 <- d[1:4]
d2[[3]] <- lapply(split(d, 1:nrow(d)), `[`, c(3, 5))
dcast(
  d2, cntry + sex ~ year, value.var="indicator", 
  fun.aggregate=function(x) {
    if(!length(x)) return(NA_real_)
    xs <- do.call(rbind, x)
    xs <- xs[complete.cases(xs), ]
    if(nrow(xs)) xs[order(as.numeric(xs$source)), "indicator"][[1L]] else NA_real_
} )
```

Produces:

```
  cntry  sex  1960  1970  1980
1    BE male 105.5 101.2 101.5
2    DE male   2.3 101.4    NA
3    GE male    NA   1.4    NA
```

Note I added 100 to "Eurostat" value to make them distinguishable from the others since in this sample set they seemed to be equal.

Basically, we cheat by turning the `indicator` column into a column of list items containing both the indicator and the source, and then we use `fun.aggregate` to pick the item from each group with the lowest source value (note we reset the factors so the most desirable source has the lowest level).